# Is it possible to use Django with Ajax to do live search?

Tags: ajax, django, search

I would like to implement search function on Django 
but I have to do it with Ajax.

I have to know that how Django will connect with Ajax
and do query to search in real time character by character.

Is there any how to or document to implement it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

1. You need to add CSRF token in your ajax calls (javascript files)
2. Create a view and handle the ajax request (django views file)
3. Perform your ajax request and handle the response.(javascript files)

Here is a tutorial, how to use [ajax in django](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/performing-ajax-post-requests-in-django/)